# React Native Navigation set image name with navigation.getParam()

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

My frist question on Stackoverflow :)

I'am using React Navigation. How can i load a image by the value of navigation.getParam('Country')?. This Image isn't loading (error code 500)

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { isLoading: true}
      const { navigation } = this.props;
      this.number = navigation.getParam('number');
      this.country = navigation.getParam('country');
    }
    return (
      <View style={bubble.container}>
        <Text>{this.country}</Text>
        <Image source={require('./img/flags/'+ this.country +'.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30}}/>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <View style={bubble.wrapper}>
                                    <Text selectable>{item.text}</Text>
                                    <View style={bubble.footer}>
                                      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                                        <Text style={bubble.sender}>{item.sender}</Text>
                                      </View>
                                      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                                        <Text style={bubble.time}><TimeAgo time={item.datetime} interval={20000}/></Text>
                                      </View>
                                    </View>
                                  </View>}
        />
      </View>
    );
```

Comment: Where are you loading the image?

Comment: Sorry, i have add it to my code

Comment: You won't have the params available during constructor please use it componentDidMount. That will be the best choice

Comment: Where is your render menthod? try moving `const { navigation } = this.props;
this.number = navigation.getParam('number');this.country = navigation.getParam('country');` to render menthod and see whehther you got any params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have load my image by URL

```
        <Image source={{uri: 'http://192.168.1.222/img/'+ countryvar + '.png'}} style={{width: 30, height: 30}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your img is available in your path of the JS code,

assume your file of the js code is `Country.js`, so, the structure of your folder should be :

```
--Country.js (File)
--img (folder)
  --flags (folder)
    --country.png (an image)
```

and then, try to change your code look's like this:

```
render(){
  const {country} = this.props.navigation.state.params
  return (
    <View style={bubble.container}>
      <Text>{country}</Text>
      <Image source={require('./img/flags/'+ country +'.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30}}/>
      <FlatList
        ..your setting
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Don't need to declare the `params` in `constructor`, you can declare the `param` of `React Navigation` in `componentDidMount()/componentWillMount()/ even in render(){}`

Comment: If i use a normal variable without getParam() its working.

Comment: what do you mean about `normal variable`?